# How can I build a retaining wall which looks like a fence?

Tags: fence, retaining-wall, gardening

The back fence of the garden is on top of a very weird, small slope. I want to level out the garden by going down. I need ideas on how to build a retaining wall, to look like part of the fence.

I’m not wanting to build a garden feature of sleepers etc. I was thinking of sliding fence panels and gravel boards out, digging out the slope and putting in more gravel boards, but the post cement is stopping this from working.

[image]

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended and design-oriented. Neither are ideal on this site. We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then see if you can revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: Nothing design orientated about it. How do you build a retaining wall, integrated to an already established fence. Without ripping out the fence and starting all over again.

Comment: Regardless, it's not clear what you're asking. Integrated how? Fences and retaining walls are usually separate structures as they have different purposes and requirements. What is "post cement"? Do you mean what looks from here like a slab under the fence? In what way will the grade change? Please revise to add detail and be more specific. Help us help you.

Comment: Guessing you're in the UK, or at least not the US, by the look of the fence? I think your idea could work but you'd have to take out the existing fence posts and put in new ones with the base below the new level or the whole thing could fall over if they're not set deep enough.

Comment: Is it really the look of a retaining wall you're concerned about or are you actually trying to save work and expense? Different solutions...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from putting a fence in front of a wall.

The retaining wall will probably be stone or concrete.  Put a taller fence in front of it if that's the aesthetic you're going for.  Trying to extend your current fence down is probably a no-go.  Absolutely do not use a wooden fence for a retaining wall barrier.  And building the barrier so that it's even with your current fence will mean digging up your neighbor's yard.

Comment: If it's not too tall, the retaining wall could also be made of stacked railroad ties, suitably tied together with spikes, etc.